# How To Remove First Three Line In A File

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have an excel file that I need to remove the earliest three dates from,based on another column.

```
        Column A Column B Column C
        Member  Claim          Date
Row1    1234    1111          01/01/2017
Row2    1234    1112          02/01/2017
Row3    1234    1113          03/01/2017
Row4    1234    1114          04/01/2017
Row5    1234    1115          05/01/2017
Row6    1234    1116          06/01/2017
Row7    222     1117          01/01/2017
Row8    222     1118          02/01/2017
```

This is test data, my real file has hundreds of lines and hundreds of members. I need to remove the earliest three per member.
I only want to see the last 3 lines for Member 1234
I have tried using a conditional format, however this has not worked. 
Could somebody suggest either a excel formula, or VBA solution?

I am also open to a SQL Solution. 
I am unsure how I would write this.

I have

```
Select a.mem, count(a.claim) from Temp a
group by a.mem;
```

Comment: Filtering / Sorting? If no, where do you wanna see the records? Only display these three or show them in a popup or what exactly? Do you want to show them on button click or always filter them?

Comment: I am open to ideas. I need to get the first 3 earliest lines removed from my set of files. If there was something that I could run that would delete this out that would be best. However, if I could even highlight them I could simply remove them manually.

Comment: Your question could be more specific and include cell references, but the function =(OFFSET()) should be what you are looking for. See my answer below for further help - though I believe my answer selects the last three lines (as your question was previously phrased).

Comment: They are columns A & B, I am literally open to suggestion as I have never done this before so it is quite difficult to be specific.

Comment: That is a typical task for SQL via ADODB.

Comment: Thanks, I was specifically trying to see if it was possible in excel, if it's not then that's ok

Comment: @omegastripes How would I go about this on SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved issue using SQL

```
Create Table Temp as
SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.mem_no ORDER BY a.status_dt) as Squence
FROM Temp_DETAIL a


Create table Temp_2 as 
Select * 
from Temp b 
where b.squence <='3';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=(OFFSET(FIRST_Member, COUNTA(RANGE:RANGE)-3,0,3,1))
```

Where `FIRST_Member` is the first cell reference you want from the first three values. `RANGE:RANGE` is the range of the cells you want for the first three values.

If you want just the last three lines from a member, add an =(IF()) format. This should be close to what you are looking for, but your question lacks precise cell references.

```
=(IF(A1='1234', OFFSET(FIRST_Member, COUNTA(RANGE:RANGE)-3,0,3,1) )
```

Comment: This isn't working as of yet, I have put in my reference of B:B but this is giving me an error. Will this work on an entire spreadsheet for me? As in I want to find the earliest three records per member (In which I have thousands in a file)

Comment: If you have the exact values for the date you are looking for (assume these dates are 123, 124, 125), then this will work: IFS(B:B=123,INDEX(Col_Return(MATCH(123,Col_That_Matches_Date,0)),B:B=124,INDEX(Col_Return(MATCH(124,Col_That_Matches_Date,0)),B:B=125,INDEX(Col_Return(MATCH(123,Col_That_Matches_Date,0))). I may be missing a parenthesis, but I cannot format here.

Comment: I have expanded my question now. This won't work for me, I need to remove the earliest three lines based on the date column per member.

Comment: If you just need to filter the dates, just select DATA > FILTER > CUSTOM FILTER and set those values.

Comment: I need it to be based on the member number? Example member 1234 I want his earliest three dates to be removed, then everything else left. The next member I want to have the same done for and so on. I have about 500 members?